# How to set Filter Values in LinQ with SQL Query Text?

Tags: linq

I am using LINQ for my database application.
So I can write things like:

```
        using (ShuttleDataContext dc = Config.GetNewShuttleDBConnection())
        {
            List<RefState> states = (from a in dc.RefStates select a).ToList();

            return states;
        }
```

Know I have to handle the requierement, that I have to filter from this database by SQL strings, e.g. a filter string: "ID like '7%'" or "Name = 'Red'".

Of course normaly I would write something like .Where(a => a.Name == "Red"), but it's nearly impossible to map every filterexpression to a where clause... So is there a method to have native T-SQL in an Linq-List?

Comment: Does it have to be native T-SQL, or would this be sufficient? http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't just provide the filter condition, but you can use [`ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx) to execute an arbitrary SQL statement and map that to your LINQ types:

```
List<RefState> states = dc.ExecuteQuery<RefState>(
    "SELECT * FROM RefStates WHERE ID LIKE '7%'").ToList();
```

Comment: Not possible, because I allready have my states-List when I have to filter it.